# How can I hold funds using transfer_group in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

My client has a business where multiple vendors can rent their clothes. Is it possible that I can hold funds with transfer_group until a renter confirms that the package is ok? In a worst-case scenario, this can take longer than 7 days.
How would can I go about with the stripe API to solve this problem.
First I need to hold the funds until the package arrives from the vendor to the client when the client confirms that everything is ok I'll take a cut in the commission and transfer it to the vendor.
What API scheme do I need to realize this?